# MySQL - Enabling Safe Updates for Everyone

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-administration

I'm teaching a database class, and I have my students connect to a MySQL database via phpMyAdmin to practice queries, etc...

We are getting to the point now where we are learning the SQL `UPDATE` statement and I would like to make sure someone doesn't issue an UPDATE without a `WHERE` clause and therefore update the entire table...

I kind of assumed that `sql_safe_updates` would be set to 1 by default, but that doesn't seem to be the case on the cloud based server that I'm utilizing for the class.  I can't seem to find anywhere that documents how to set `sql_safe_updates` to on for all users in the MySQL instance.

So, I'm looking to see if any of these options are available and will work for this situation:

1. Can I startup MySQL with `sql_safe_updates` set to "1" via the configuration file or another method?
2. Can I create a startup script in phpMyAdmin that runs `SET sql_safe_updates=1` when a user connects to the database via phpMyAdmin?

Any help would be truly appreciated, I really didn't think this was going to pose such a challenge!

Comment: Excellent question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to set updates mode on in phpMyAdmin -

1. Log on to phpMyAdmin with a admin account
2. Goto the "Variables" tab.
3. This lists all of the variables for the system.  Search for "safe"
4. This should find the "sql safe updates" variable, which you can then edit and set to "On"

After doing so, you will be in safe updates mode, which prevents `UPDATES` or `DELETES` without `WHERE` clauses.

The setting seems to persist across login attempts.

Comment: The setting does not persist after restart

Answer (score 0):

you can ether turn of in settings or use

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
your statement; 
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

or the other way round.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
your statement; 
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

Just don't forget to use a semi-colon at the end of each statement.

If using MYSQL workbench use 
Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor -> SQL Editor
remove Forbid UPDATE and DELETE statements without a WHERE clause (safe updates)

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks - but this would require the users (students) to issue the SQL_SAFE_UPDATES statement each time they connect, correct?  I'd like to turn it on system wide for all users (or have it in an automated script when they log on) and not rely on them to remember to run this command.